# matlab-prettifier: How to insert a green-colored dots as prebreak argument?

Tags: color, luatex, matlab-prettifier

In this MWE, how can I color  `\ldots`, which is the `prebreak` argument,  in green without getting errors?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathdots,xcolor}


\lstset{
    language = Matlab,
    style = Matlab-editor,
    breakatwhitespace = false,
    prebreak=\ldots
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
theta2= atan( abs( BP{nxBP}(1,3)-BP{nxBP-1}(size(BP{nxBP-1},1),3) ) / ( abs( BP{nxBP}(1,2)-BP{nxBP-1}(size(BP{nxBP-1},1),2) ) ) ); % some comment
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `prebreak={\color{green}\ldots}` and got an error. What did work was to shove the green dots into a savebox first:

```
\newsavebox{\dotbox}
\sbox{\dotbox}{{\color{green}\ldots}}   

\lstset{
    language = Matlab,
    style = Matlab-editor,
    breakatwhitespace = false,
    prebreak={\usebox{\dotbox}}
}
```

Note that, when I tested, I removed some packages from your code (luatex85, fontspec) to get it to compile on my computer. However, I don't expect that to affect your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually, this is only a small part of my original code. I actually need `fontspec` package to change the document main font.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - This code works just fine with LuaLaTeX and the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @Mico I just tested it now, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - In that case, you should delete your earlier comment. I'll also delete my comments shortly.